# How can I fix this line spacing in Word when combining Chinese characters with English?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, line-spacing

At the moment, I'm having to deal with this when writing my dissertation:

[image]

Whenever a line contains Chinese characters, the line spacing gets messed up; making them smaller doesn't help and just makes them unreadable, and changing the line spacing between individual lines doesn't make it look any better. I have the same problem whether the line spacing is 1.0, 1.15 or 1.5 (it's currently 1.5)

Can anyone suggest a way to fix it? I don't want to submit this with such ugly paragraphs.

Comment: You could try using a font with smaller vertical metrics.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the line spacing to a multiple value (1.5), open the **Paragraph** dialog box, and set the **Line spacing** field to **Exactly** and the **At** field to a value that is 1.5 times the font size that you're using (**15 pt** if your font size is 10 pt, **18 pt** if it's 12 pt, and so on).

Answer (score 1):

I think you must find a UNICODE font for your document (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font) and apply the same font for Chinese and Non Chinese characters. I tried with Arial and Times New Roman and the line height is the same for all rows.

Edit: I'm not realy sure the problem is UNICODE font or not, but tryng some fonts the line height work.